# Getting divided bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm writing my thesis in LyX using Biblatex.

Would it be possibly to get an output bibliography that is subdivided into one section with the work of my main subject (Wittgenstein) referred to with abbreviations of his works and another section with other authors referred to authoryear-style?

**EDIT:**

I've managed to get my bibliography subdivided with this:

```
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Works by Wittgenstein},keyword=witt]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Works by others},notkeyword=witt]
```

Two questions remain:

**1.**

Would it be possible to have abbreviated titles listed in the first division of the bibliography (as it is convention in my field) - like this:

[image]

**2.**
If thats not possible, is there a way to add the abbreviated title as some of the data displayed in the bibliography in away akin to the "Referenced in the text as xxx" in this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the biblatex manual on shorthands. What I think you are looking for in `biblatex` terms is a list of shorthands for the Wittgenstein works (where you will also want to set a shorthand field) and a bibliography for the rest.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Only one problem: in the shorthands entry the name isn't reversed "Surname, Name"-style as it is in the bibliography, but plainly "Name Surname. Is there any fix for this? Or better yet: could I omit the name in the shorthands list (is has the heading "Works by Ludwig Wittgenstein" anyway)?

Comment: I've posted the above related but new question separately [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112013/reversed-name-in-shorthand-divion-of-bibliography)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biblatex has a number of different ways of doing subdivided bibliographies (including `keywords` and `categories` for topic division). But for the sort of use case you have in mind what you really want is the `shorthand` field which sets abbreviations which can be explained in a list of shorthands using `\printshorthands`. It's well explained in section 3 of the `biblatex` manual.