# Reversed name in shorthand division of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

Using Biblatex with LyX I've managed to get a subdivided bibliography almost the the way I want it. The idea is to cite the key works with abbreviations that are conventional to my subject. For this I have used `shorthands` like this:

```
\printbibheading
\printshorthands[heading=subbibliography,title={Værker af Wittgenstein}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Andre værker},notkeyword=witt]
```

This is an extract from the .bib file with one item with a `shorthand` entry and one without (I've given the `shorthand` items the keyword "witt", so that I can exclude them from being printed in the regular bibliography):

```
@BOOK{rorty_philosophy_1980,
  title = {Philosophy and the Mirror of Nature},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  year = {1980},
  author = {Rorty, Richard},
}

@BOOK{wittgenstein_certainty_1979,
  title = {On certainty},
  publisher = {Blackwell},
  year = {1979},
  author = {Wittgenstein, Ludwig},
  editor = {Anscombe, {G.E.M} and Wright, {G.H.} von and Paul, Denis},
  address = {Oxford},
  shorthand = {OC},
  keywords = {witt},
}
```

The output is this:

[image: Output]

The only problem is that the names in the shorthands division aren't reversed "Surname, Name"-style like the other part of the bibliography. How would I go about changing that?

Comment: We need to see the bibliography - how are you defining your shorthands?

Comment: I've edited in a sample from my .bib file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible problem is in the way the biblatex style used defines the formatting instruction for the names. For the bibliography it seems it use `last-first`, while the standard definition for the shorthands inherit the formatting instruction form the bibliography entry, but it uses `first-last` formatting for the names; Namely, the  definition is:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthands}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
  \finentry}
```

Thus, one can change the  definition above

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthands}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
  \finentry}
```

or changing `last-first` to `default` or `last-first/first-last`. To be sure we need a minimal working example and knowing the `style` used.

Comment: For the record I use the style `authoryear-ibid`. Adding the definition to the preamble did the trick.